# If $G$ is an abelian group with $35$ elements, then it's cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

I have to show that if $G$ is an abelian group with $35$ elements, then it's cyclic. I know the chinise remainder, but I can't use it. This is how I do:

Let $g\in G\backslash \{0\}$. Suppose $5g=0$. Then $$0=35g=5g+7g=7g$$ and thus $g$ is of order $5$ and $7$. Since $\gcd(5,7)=1$, we have a contradiction. We can reasoning as well if $7g=0$. Therefore $g$ as order $35$ and thus it's cyclic.

**Q1) Is it correct ?**

**Q2) I have the impression that it works if $G$ is not abelian (with the multiplicative notation). So is the fact that $G$ abelian is necessary ?**

Comment: Why is $35g = 5g + 7g$?

Comment: If your conclusion is that there cannot be an element in $G$ of order $5$, then I am afraid you are wrong, even if $G$ is cyclic of order $35$, there exists an element of order $5$.

Comment: Every group with $35$ elements is cyclic, this is [because](https://yiminge.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/all-groups-of-order-n-are-cyclic-iff/) $(35,\phi(35))=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $35 = 5\cdot 7$, by Cauchy $G$ has an element $x$ of order $5$ and an element $y$ of order $7$. What is the order of $x+y$? Note that

$$5(x+y) = 5x + 5y = 5y \neq 0$$
$$7(x+y) = 7x + 7y = 7x \neq 0$$

So, the order of $x+y$ cannot be $5$ or $7$. By Lagrange, the order must divide $|G|=35$. Since $x+y\neq 0$, we conclude that $x+y$ has order 35 and generates $G$.